# Spring Kafka, Spring Cloud Stream, and Avro compatibility Unknown magic byte

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I have a problem deserializing messages from Kafka topics.  The messages have been serialized using spring-cloud-stream and Apache Avro.  I am reading them using Spring Kafka and trying to deserialise them.  If I use spring-cloud to both produce and consume the messages, then I can deserialize the messages fine.  The problem is when I consume them with Spring Kafka and then try to deserialize.

I am using a Schema Registry (both the spring-boot Schema Registry for development, and also a Confluent schema in production), but the deserialization problems seem to occur before event calling the Schema Registry.

Its hard to post all the relevant code on this question, so I have posted it in a repo in git hub: https://github.com/robjwilkins/avro-example

The object I am sending over the topic is just a simple pojo:

```
@Data
public class Request {
  private String message;
}
```

The code which produces messages on Kafka looks like this:

```
@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class ProducerController {

  private final MessageChannels messageChannels;

  @GetMapping("/produce")
  public void produceMessage() {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setMessage("hello world");
    Message<Request> requestMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(request).build();
    log.debug("sending message");
    messageChannels.testRequest().send(requestMessage);
  }
}
```

and application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application.name: avro-producer
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer.group-id: avro-producer
  cloud:
    stream:
      schema-registry-client.endpoint: http://localhost:8071
      schema.avro.dynamic-schema-generation-enabled: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}
      bindings:
        test-request:
          destination: test-request
          contentType: application/*+avro
```

Then I have a consumer:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TopicListener {

    @KafkaListener(topics = {"test-request"})
    public void listenForMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, Request> consumerRecord) {
        log.info("listenForMessage. got a message: {}", consumerRecord);
        consumerRecord.headers().forEach(header -> log.info("header. key: {}, value: {}", header.key(), asString(header.value())));
    }

    private String asString(byte[] byteArray) {
        return new String(byteArray, Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

And the project which consumes has application.yaml config:

```
spring:
  application.name: avro-consumer
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: avro-consumer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
#      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      properties:
        schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8071
```

When the consumer gets a message it results in an exception:

```
2019-01-30 20:01:39.900 ERROR 30876 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: null

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition test-request-0 at offset 43. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

I have stepped through the deserialization code to the point where this exception is thrown

```
public abstract class AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe {
....
private ByteBuffer getByteBuffer(byte[] payload) {
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(payload);
  if (buffer.get() != 0) {
    throw new SerializationException("Unknown magic byte!");
  } else {
    return buffer;
  }
}
```

It is happening because the deserializer checks byte contents of the serialized object (byte array) and expects it to be 0, however it is not. Hence the reason I question whether the spring-cloud-stream MessageConverter which serialized the object is compatible with the io.confluent  object which I am using to deserialize the object.  And if they are not compatible, what do I do?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't edit the stack trace; show the whole thing. `Cause by:` on their own are useless.

Comment: If at any point you pushed a string (or non-avro) value onto the topic, then `KafkaAvroDeserializer` will not be able to read it...

Comment: @GaryRussell I have not edited the stacktrace - that is all that displays on the console.  Have added more description of problem too

Comment: @cricket_007 - its possible that I have published a message with a string payload, however I have reset the topic offsets to latests to ensure any old messages are not picked up.

Comment: Well, all I can say is it's not a proper stack trace; in addition to `Caused by:` entries, a normal stack trace contains call stack information (classes/methods/line numbers). That's why it's called a **stack** trace. If you didn't edit it, perhaps your logging subsystem is configured to suppress this important information, which would be very odd indeed.

Comment: All I can really say is based on my experience with this error. If you have moved to the latest offset, then the consumer would read nothing as there are no new messages. If you started a producer again sending data, and **then** the consumer has the same error - then the problem remains; the messages were not serialized using the Confluent Serializers... I don't know what this `@Data` annotation is, but it is not used by the Confluent examples https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/5.1.0-post/clients/avro

Comment: @Data is a Lombok annotation - it just auto creates getter/setter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of this problem is that the producer is using spring-cloud-stream to post messages to Kafka, but the consumer uses spring-kaka.  The reasons for this are:

- The existing system is already well established and uses spring-cloud-stream
- A new consumer is required to listen to multiple topics using the same method, binding only on a csv list of topic names
- There is a requirement to consume a collection of messages at once, rather than individually, so their contents can be written in bulk to a database.

Spring-cloud-stream doesn't current allow the consumer to bind a listener to multiple topics, and there is no way to consume a collection of messages at once (unless I'm mistaken).

I have found a solution which doesn't require any changes to the producer code which uses spring-cloud-stream to publish messages to Kafka.  Spring-cloud-stream uses a `MessageConverter` to manage serialisation and deserialisation. In the `AbstractAvroMessageConverter` there are methods: `convertFromInternal` and `convertToInternal` which handle the transformation to/from a byte array.  My solution was to extend this code (creating a class which extends `AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter`), so I could reuse much of the spring-cloud-stream functionality, but with an interface that can be accessed from my spring-kafka `KafkaListener`.  I then amended my TopicListener to use this class to do the conversion:

The converter:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AvroKafkaMessageConverter extends AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter {

  public AvroKafkaMessageConverter(SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient) {
    super(schemaRegistryClient, new NoOpCacheManager());
  }

  public <T> T convertFromInternal(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Class<T> targetClass,
      Object conversionHint) {
    T result;
    try {
      byte[] payload = (byte[]) consumerRecord.value();

      Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
      consumerRecord.headers().forEach(header -> headers.put(header.key(), asString(header.value())));

      MimeType mimeType = messageMimeType(conversionHint, headers);
      if (mimeType == null) {
        return null;
      }

      Schema writerSchema = resolveWriterSchemaForDeserialization(mimeType);
      Schema readerSchema = resolveReaderSchemaForDeserialization(targetClass);

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      DatumReader<Object> reader = getDatumReader((Class<Object>) targetClass, readerSchema, writerSchema);
      Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(payload, null);
      result = (T) reader.read(null, decoder);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read payload", e);
    }
    return result;
  }

  private MimeType messageMimeType(Object conversionHint, Map<String, String> headers) {
    MimeType mimeType;
    try {
      String contentType = headers.get(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
      log.debug("contentType: {}", contentType);
      mimeType = MimeType.valueOf(contentType);
    } catch (InvalidMimeTypeException e) {
      log.error("Exception getting object MimeType from contentType header", e);
      if (conversionHint instanceof MimeType) {
        mimeType = (MimeType) conversionHint;
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return mimeType;
  }

  private String asString(byte[] byteArray) {
    String theString = new String(byteArray, Charset.defaultCharset());
    return theString.replace("\"", "");
  }
}
```

The amended `TopicListener`:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TopicListener {

  private final AvroKafkaMessageConverter messageConverter;

  @KafkaListener(topics = {"test-request"})
  public void listenForMessage(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
    log.info("listenForMessage. got a message: {}", consumerRecord);
    Request request = messageConverter.convertFromInternal(
        consumerRecord, Request.class, MimeType.valueOf("application/vnd.*+avr"));
    log.info("request message: {}", request.getMessage());
  }
}
```

This solution only consumes one message at a time but can be easily modified to consume batches of messages.

The full solution is here: https://github.com/robjwilkins/avro-example/tree/develop

Answer (score 0):

You should to define deserializer explicitly, by creating `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` and your `TopicListener` bean in a config, something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class TopicListenerConfig {

@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

@Value(("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}"))
private String groupId;


@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.wilkins.avro.consumer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public TopicListener topicListener() {
    return new TopicListener();
}
}
```

Comment: Note: Question is using Avro, not the `JsonDeserializer`, which cannot read that data

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the binding to use a Kafka Serializer natively instead.

Set the producer property `useNativeEncoding` to `true` and configure the serializer using the `...producer.configuration` Kafka properties.

**EDIT**

**Example:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
# Generic binding properties
      bindings:
        input:
          consumer:
            use-native-decoding: true
          destination: so54448732
          group: so54448732
        output:
          destination: so54448732
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true
# Kafka-specific binding properties
      kafka:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                value.deserializer: com.example.FooDeserializer
          output:
            producer:
              configuration:
                value.serializer: com.example.FooSerializer
```

Comment: I suggest you open [an issue here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream) with your suggestions for improvements.

Comment: it would be very helpful if could you provide an example of the producer / consumer properties that I'd need to set please? thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  My example is not using spring-cloud-stream as a consumer, which is where I am having the problem with deserialization though?

Comment: It doesn't matter; I showed the use of native serializer/deserialers on both sides for completeness. Your question is about compatibility between the message converter and the avro deserializer. Using native encoding takes the message converters out of the picture; the payload is sent to the Kafka client directly as the `ProducerRecord.value` and the serialization is done by Kafka; Spring takes no part in it. If you are still having problems when using native encoding, then the problem lies elsewhere, perhaps in the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this has saved my day using nativeencoding and spring:
  cloud:
    stream:

## Generic binding properties

```
  bindings:
    input:
      consumer:
        use-native-decoding: true
      destination: so54448732
      group: so54448732
    output:
      destination: so54448732
      producer:
        use-native-encoding: true
```

## Kafka-specific binding properties

```
  kafka:
    bindings:
      input:
        consumer:
          configuration:
            value.deserializer: com.example.FooDeserializer
      output:
        producer:
          configuration:
            value.serializer: com.example.FooSerializer
```